# Python 3 Omit Characters - Naive methods

Tags: python, for-loop, replace

I have  a very lengthy text file which I opened and saved to a string variable of which I am looking to remove all special characters and replace it with a space. I am not allowed to import other libraries, so I have to keep it pretty naive. I figured running a for loop through my text file, comparing to see if the given punctuation is in the text, and replace it with a " ". I would then print the updated text string, for some reason (probably a simple fix for a more trained eye) I can't get it to remove the special characters. Per instructions, I need to remove the special characters first, before splitting the text file's string into a list of words.

```
alice_txt = "Hi! Is my name Alice? I can\"t be too sure about that!" 
def omit_punctuation():
    punct_string = ",.!?;:][-\""
    punct_list = [",",".","!","?",";",":","]","[","-","\""]
    punct_omit = ""
    for mark in punct_list: 
        if mark in alice_txt:
            punct_omit += alice_txt.replace(mark, " ")
    print(punct_omit)
    
omit_characters()
```

Output:

> Hi  Is my name Alice? I can"t be too sure about that Hi! Is my name Alice  I can"t be too sure about that!Hi! Is my name Alice? I can t be too sure about that!

Instead of the desired: Hi  Is my name Alice I cant be too sure about that

I've tried the for loop with both punctuation_list as well as :_string. It looks like (as the code states) it's looking at each mark, and when it finds that mark, it does the replacement for each successive mark in the iteration, but then does not store the replacement for each next iteration. What am I not understanding in this method?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  Your code fragment fails to execute, and you haven't posted the required output samples.

Comment: @Prune sorry about that! I think I fixed my post now

Comment: *Much* better!  I removed my closure vote and reversed my down-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the character isn't found in `punctuation_list`, you need to add it to `punct_omit`. Otherwise, all you get are the spaces, not the ordinary characters.

You don't need to call `replace()`, just append a space to `punct_omit`.

Also, you should be iterating over the text, not `punctuation_string`.

```
def omit_characters(text):
    punctuation_string = ",.!?;:][-\""
    punct_omit = ""
    for mark in text: 
        if mark in puctuation_string:
            punct_omit += " "
        else:
            punct_omit += mark
    print(punct_omit)

omit_characters(alice_text)
```

You can also do it with `replace`. Then you need to use the previous replaced string as the input on each iteration:

```
def omit_characters(text):
    punctuation_string = ",.!?;:][-\""
    for mark in punctuation_string:
        text = text.replace(mark, " ")
    print(text)
```

Comment: When I read your code, it makes sense and it seems like it will do what I want it to, unfortunately, my output is still coming out all wonky.
Using the example string in my edited post above. My output when I ran your code was:
HiHi  Is my name Alice? I can"t be too sure about that  Is my name AliceHi! Is my name Alice  I can"t be too sure about that! I canHi! Is my name Alice? I can t be too sure about that!t be too sure about thatHi  Is my name Alice? I can"t be too sure about that

Comment: Thanks so much! So it seems like the replace function was not needed/it contradicts the += assignment. Is that correct? Is there a better (still naive) way to do this with .replace()?

Comment: Thank you so much! I believe you helped me out a few months ago with another class, so again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following could work if you only use ascii characters. It replaces the characterset. A character is basically just a number (0-128), which can be displayed in any way (the characterset), so replacing the characterset with your variation would solve the issue.
You'd need to replace the not-allowed characters in the `keyspace` with `\x20` to get a `" "`.

```
def int_to_charset(val, charset):
    output = ""
    while val > 0:
        val, digit = divmod(val, len(charset))
        output += charset[digit]
    # reverse the characters in the output and return
    return output[::-1]


def charset_to_int(s, charset):
    output = 0
    for char in s:
        output = output * len(charset) + charset.index(char)
    return output


def change_charset(s, original_charset, target_charset):
    intermediate_integer = charset_to_int(s, original_charset)
    return int_to_charset(intermediate_integer, target_charset)


origspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\x20\x20#$%&\'()*+\x20-\x20/:;\x20@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'

text = "Hi! Is my name Alice? I can\"t be too sure about that!"

print(change_charset(text, origspace, keyspace))
```

Comment: Was "not allowed to import other libraries" unclear?

Comment: This is really detailed @Alex, but I'm really new to Python (5 weeks in) and a lot of this is out of my scope. I'd love to be able to get to this level at some point but for now its really over my head. Thank you for your time and effort though! Will love to come back to this in a few weeks time to see if I can break it down myself!